# Problems reading multiple files line by line when using SequenceInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm reading multiple files line-by line, and found `SequenceInputStream` handy. Here's how I use it:

```
try (
    InputStream in = new SequenceInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1),new FileInputStream(file2));
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(source)) {
    while ( reader.hasNext ()) {
        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
    }
}
```

However it has a peculiar problem. Lets say that:

**File1**

```
a
b
```

**File2**

```
c
d
```

Then the executed code will output:

```
a
bc
d
```

It seems that it does not distinguish between lines from separate files, is there a way to fix this? (yes, I really need to merge multiple InputStreams into one)

Comment: Maybe `file1` does not end with a newline.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's a hack. It would "work", but generally, would you write newlines to the provided input files you're about to read? That's just crazy

Comment: Without a newline why would you expect a separate line? How can the Scanner know when one file ends and the next one begin when its source is a single InputStream?

Comment: That's not the point. I read several files, and I expect to get their lines, I think that's reasonable.

Comment: It's not reasonable because it is impossible. How could the Scanner *possibly* know where one file ends and the next begins? The SequenceInputStream, by definition, takes multiple files and simply concatenates them to form a single inputstream which you then pass to the Scanner instance.

Answer (score 2):

`SequenceInputStream` hides the `EOF` characters from the all the wrapped files except for the last file:

```
 public int read() throws IOException {
    if (in == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int c = in.read();
    if (c == -1) {
        nextStream();
        return read();
    }
    return c;
}
```

So if the files don't end with a new line, then the first line of file2 will get appended to the last line of file1.

If you really need to use a single inputStream and you need to have separate lines to separate each file, you probably have to write your own InputStream implementation that checks that there is a newline character as the last line of the file and if not, inserts one as part the `read()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sequencing multiple streams and want to ensure that each end in a [line separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29), wrap each stream in a [`FilterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) that returns an extra line separator at the end, if not in the filtered stream.

Comment: Care to add an example?

Answer (score 1):

As other answers pointed out, I could create my own `SequenceInputStream` implementation, or wrap each stream into `FilterInputStream`. However I think I found a simpler solution: just insert streams that provide *endline* between my file streams.

```
InputStream in = new SequenceInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(file1),
    new SequenceInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream("\n".getBytes()), // gives an endline between the provided files
        new FileInputStream(file2)));
```

Comment: That'll work in this case but if the file already ended with a newline this solution will give you an extra blank line.

Comment: well, extra blank line is not that bad, I can live with it.